# The influence of ? in the regex string

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following Python code:

```
>>> re.search(r'.*(99)', 'aa99bb').groups()
('99',)
>>> re.search(r'.*(99)?', 'aa99bb').groups()
(None,)
```

I don't understand why I don't catch 99 in the second example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the `.*` first matches the entire string. At that point, it's not possible to match `99` any more, and since the group is optional, the regex engine stops because it has found a successful match.

If on the other hand the group is mandatory, the regex engine has to backtrack into the `.*`.

Compare the following debug sessions from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) (the part of the string matched by `.*` is highlighted in yellow, the part matched by `(99)` in blue):

`.*(99)`:

[image]

---

`.*(99)?`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, a good choice might be `[^9]*(99)?`.
No backtracking, instead matches anything other than 9 followed by an optional 99. Doesn't work if you want to ignore 9s before the 99 though.

```
>>> re.search(r'[^9]*(99)?', 'aa99bb').groups()
('99',)
>>> re.search(r'[^9]*(99)?', 'aa9x99bb').groups()
(None,)
```